# ifstream::read doesnot append '\0'

Tags: c++, ifstream

`ifstream::read` just reads `n` bytes into a buffer, but doesn't append `'\0'` at the end of the buffer, right? Then when I use the buffer, how does it know the end of the buffer?

Should I manually append a `'\0'` at the end of the buffer?

Answer (score 4):

The `ifstream` is used for reading from a file, binary or text. When dealing with a binary file with `read`, one cannot be sure the origin of a zero byte (from the file itself or appended by `read`) so read does not append a zero to destination buffer.

If you are working on a text file, then you can use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/), and receive a `std::string`:

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, you need to manually append it to the end of the buffer: `buffer[length] = '\0';` if you want a null terminator.
When you call `write` you can also specify the length of the output: `std::cout.write(buffer, length);` which will output only `length` number of data to tell it when to stop requiring you not to use the null terminator.
I would look into `std::getline` and `std::string` for a more robust approach though.

Comment: Why does he need to do that? The `read` method is intended for raw data, with no special interpretation for '\0'.

Comment: @DanielKO: I just realized you are talking about appending the null terminator before passing the buffer to `read`. The question specifically talks about using the buffer after the call to `read`.

Comment: No, I'm talking about there is no need for any terminator when you are reading binary data. If you are talking about strings, then `istream::read` is not the function you should be using.

Comment: @DanielKO: The OP is reading text data. That's why I said to use `std::string` and `std::getline` for a better approach.

Comment: The OP mentions reading bytes to a buffer, and appears to be confused about the usage of '\0'. Strings are only mentioned in the answers, by deducing from '\0' in the question that the data is a string. I find it common for people to misunderstand the use of '\0' as if it was some kind of magic marker the same way people misunderstand "EOF" as a magic byte marking the end of files. Alas, my answer is the only one pointing out the distinction that dealing with binary data has no use for null terminators, and was downvoted.

Comment: @DanielKO: Yeah, I always hate anonymous downvotes that don't give a reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading into a `std::string` say, with `std::getline`, then string carries a length - `std::string` is not terminated by `'\0'` as C-style `char*` strings are.  If you read into std::string and then use string.c_str() then that is null terminated.  You can use this for a C-style string.

If you are reading into `char*` you must supply a length - that is how many bytes are read independent of any `'\0'` are found.  In this case you should manually append a '\0' at the end of the buffer.

Comment: `std::string` is guaranteed to be null-terminated in C++11, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever you want at the end of the buffer, as long as there is space for it.
`istream::read` doesn't tell you how many bytes it read; it either reads everything you asked for, or changes the state of the stream to fail/eof.

If you want to handle the case where you might have less bytes than expected, use `istream::readsome`, it returns the number of bytes extracted.

As other answers mentioned, if you are dealing with strings, use functions that read strings, like `std::getline`, or the `>>` extractors. `istream::read` is for binary data - in which case `std::streambuf` is usually more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ifstream::gcount()` to determine the number of characters read in the `read()` operation.